# Having troubles changing value of global variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a battleships game to practice my coding, however I am having trouble changing the value of a global variable.

---

```
turnsover = 0
diff = 0
ship_row = 0
ship_col = 0

def difficulty():

    global diff
    global turnsover
    diff = input("Please select a difficulty\n 1=Easy \n 2=Meduim \n 3=Hard \n 4=VS Machine\n")
    if diff.isdigit():
        diff = int(diff)

        if int(diff) not in range(1,5):
            print("Please select a correct difficulty level")
            difficulty()

        if diff == 1:
            turnsover == 20
            print("Difficulty level: Easy")

        if diff == 2:
            turnsover == 15
            print("Difficulty level: Meduim")

        if diff == 3:
            turnsover == 10
            print("Difficulty level: Hard")

        if diff == 4:
            turnsover == randint(1, 26)
            print("Difficulty level: Vs Machine")


        ####REMOVE AFTER PROD####
        print(turnsover)
    else:
        print("Please select a correct difficulty level")
        difficulty()
```

---

The prod test print of turnsover returns 0 instead of returning the new amount of turnsover (aka lifes remaining)

Comment: `turnsover == 20` That checks if `turnsover` is equal to 20.

Comment: If you want to practice then try to make the next step to be a good and responsible developer and work without `global`.

Answer (score 0):

As @MorganThrapp says, you are checking `turnsover` equality with code such as `turnsover == 10` and not assigning a value to it like so: `turnsover = 0`. `=` means *assignment* and `==` means *equality*. This should be obvious as you're *assigning* values to the global variables at the beginning of your code.